# How to link custom form fields to a user's profile?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I want to make a form that allows the registered users of my website to change their website URL. The website URL I'm referring to is the website field that can be seen in User -> Edit page ([the 'website URL' I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJbvN.jpg)). At the moment, I have a form created using a widget that allows me to receive someone's website URL, however, it does not automatically fill in their profile's website URL.

What would be the most appropriate way to 'connect' the data from the form to the user-url field? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Akb.jpg) is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Primally you need the user id to update the website field.

Then you can use `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'url', $new_value );` to update the url field ([update_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/))

You can also check the [wp_update_user function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/) if you need to update multiple fields at once (also email and password) like `wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_url' => $website ) );`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I stumbled upon [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end) that helped achieve what I was trying to do.

To add to your answer, `wp_update_user()` is used instead of `update_user_meta()` to update the url and e-mail field since they are stored in the `wp_users` table and not the `wp_usermeta` table. [credits](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end#comment94897_9786)